# Test a function with a list of bounded value with quickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to test some function with `quickCheck` do validate these function.

I need to send value in the range `1` to `40` to the function but I'm very beginner with `quickCheck` and it's modificator.

I tried :

```
myTestFunction (x,y,z) (Positive div) = ....
```

with

```
quickCheck myTestFunction
```

`div` remain positive but can take very high value (and I don't want)

What is the correct way to give div random value in the range `a` to `b` ?

Is it also possible to impose a list of value (non random) to `quickCheck` ?

Comment: Be aware that `div` is the name of Prelude function...

Comment: Ooops! I made a mistake while editing. In reality it's `ndiv` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine two parts. The first is [generation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:5)—you need to write a QuickCheck random generator that outputs numbers in your desired range. Happily, we can do this with a built-in function:

```
choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a
```

Next, we need to specify a property that uses this custom generator. This is where the [property combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:16) really come in handy. Again, the function we want is the first one in the documentation section:

```
forAll :: (Show a, Testable prop) => Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> Property
```

This lets us pass our custom generator in for a function parameter.

Putting all this together, the test case will look something like this:

```
prop_myTest (x, y, z) = forAll (choose (1, 40)) $ \ ndiv -> ...
```

The "`prop_`" naming scheme is conventionally used for QuickCheck tests. This will help people quickly understand what's going on in your code and is used by some test frameworks, so it's a good habit to get into now.